# Can't change stroke around shapes (Arrows)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, stroke

I've been using the shape tool in PS for years and suddenly, it is forcing a black stroke around my arrow and I can't change/remove it.  I worked on 5-6 other images tonight without this happening so it just cropped up on its own.

I can change it on a line, just not this arrow, or any other shapes.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The photo doesn't show the bar at the top, where you can edit the path. Could you add that?

Answer (score 1):

With a **Shape Tool** active, click the layer with the arrow, then look at the **Control Bar* across the top of the screen.

Remove the stroke there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping. The main issue here is I don't have that menu showing up like it does when I'm drawing lines etc.  Once I select the arrow (vs drawing a line for example), that menu goes away.

Comment: @ScottManthey you must *click* the little stroke box to see the pop up. You can do this before *or* after you have drawn any arrows. Simply keep the Shape Tool active.